# In a "progressive" design website, is there any data savings for people on lower spec devices?

Tags: html, css

If you declare in CSS something is `display: none;`, does the browser download the data anyway?

I always had the impression that it does. My understanding is that when downloading a web page, the browser pulls down everything from the server, and then it reads the CSS, and then displays or doesn't display what the CSS specifies. So, if you have a bunch of images in a `DIV`, and you set that `DIV` to `display: none;` the images still get downloaded, just not rendered.

This being the case, then if a "responsive" website has huge images to display for a widescreen monitor, and if someone views that page on their mobile phone, then they are still downloading those huge images, but just can't see them. This is kind of a burn for people who pay for data transfer rates, not to mention the additional time it takes to download the content, holding the user up.

Am I wrong about this? Are responsive web sites in some way saving people on lower spec devices from downloading content they won't see? Without resorting to browser detection and code on the server to determine what content to send, is there a methodology in CSS that addresses the downloading of unneeded data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, images on websites shouldn't be big. There are unwritten rules, that if a webpage, with all its resources, is larger than 500kb, then it's a big page, and needs optimization. Sadly this is the case with many bloated themes on themeforest.

Here's a few tricks to make the page smaller:

- When I'm preparing images for the web, I tend to look for a size around 70-90kb for single, large images that define the page, or 150kb if the image is at the heart of the page (like a photo on half of the screen).
- Use responsive layouts. CSS media queries (max-width), combined with using background images instead of `<img>` tags, can help you forward just the images required for a specific screen size.
- Dynamic content loading on long pages. It's like what google images does, and many tumblr themes also. Basically, you need a script that acts on scroll and resize, and is executed on the window.onload event, and what it does is figure out if there is more content to load. If there is - either use AJAX for content, or create it using javascript, from the JSON passed together with the page. As the content is created, the images are loaded. Not sooner. The AJAX approach is better for reducing traffic if you count on the majority of users not scrolling too far down the page, or if the page is really HUGE. The pre-loaded JSON is better in all other cases.

Then there's loading time, which defines 2 conflicting approaches to the subject. As you know, browsers download references in a queue. References are not downloaded in paralel, at least not all at once, so a page that has very many references, will take very long to load. This is why it is common practice to have images as sprites or font glyphs, and it has become popular to refer to scripts that combine CSS and Javascript, instead of separate CSS and JS files. For example, call this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/combine_js.php?jquery&custom-script&lightbox"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

The downside of this approach is that either all pages will include all the scripts and CSS styles, whether it needs them or not, OR that separate pages will load different script sets, but they won't get extracted from browser cache.

So, it is **better for load time and server load** to combine images into sprites, and scripts and styles into 2 single requests. However **it is better for saving traffic** to do it the old fashioned way, by referring separately, only to those files that you actually need.

Comment: Thank you for responding, and these are good tips for beginner web designers about how to optimize, but none of this actually answers the question. The question isn't about optimization, it's about the specifics of how browsers handle CSS declarations.

Comment: Well, that's what I understood from the question. Anyway, CSS defines what resources it needs, and ultimately these resources have to be downloaded from the server. And if the client requests a file, the server sends that file, even if it's a 2000x1500 image for an HTC Hero. The only thing a developer can do, is provide smaller images on the server, and specify CSS, and JavaScript where necessary, to pull just those image sizes that are appropriate. In CSS there is media query, and in Javascript there's dynamic page composition. No other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

By using Firebug to run some tests on [a web page that uses responsive design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), I've determined that the browser does **not** download media for media screen sizes outside of the one you are currently displaying. At least, not on Firefox 29 on Ubuntu. When I resized my browser window, and a new screen size declaration in the CSS was triggered, then the associated images were downloaded.

So, opposite to how I had previously understood it, this means there **are** data savings for the end user, because they are only getting the data the CSS specifies for their device.